# Was ist „fangirlen“? Und wie sagt man das auf gut Deutsch?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Ich erinnere mich, folgenden Kommentar gelesen zu haben:

> Ich fangirl(e) sie.

Was soll das bedeuten? Ist der, der dies verfasst hat, eine Frau, oder kann es auch ein Mann sein?

Comment: Klarer Fall von "kein Wort". Bis es dazu kommt, müssen wir möglicherweise noch 10 Jahre Facebook ertragen...

Comment: @tofro Dem stimme ich hauptsächlich zu. Aber wenn man eine Sprache lernt, sollte man mEn versuchen, nicht nur deren schon fest etabliertes Register zu verstehen; nicht salonfähige Ausdrücke sind manchmal schwerer. Mich wundert ein bisschen wie *cool* sich Jugendliche (und gar Nicht-So-Jugendliche) dadurch fühlen, dass sie widerstandslos so was eindeutschen.

Comment: Nennen wir es mal positiv "unbeschwerte Kreativität der Jugend" - Interessant ist es auf jeden Fall. Meine 2 pubertierenden Töchter kommen auch alle Naselang mit sprachlichen Neuschöpfungen aus dem Englischen an.

Comment: Wäre '"Fangirlen" ist eine Wortschöpfung von schreib- oder sprechfaulen Menschen' eine legitime Antwort? ;)

Comment: @0xC0000022L Im Nachhinein wäre die tatsächliche Frage „wie sagt man *fangirlen* auf Deutsch?“, denn *verehren* klingt nicht so ganz passend. Nun ist aber vielleicht spät.

Comment: @c.p.: es ist nie zu spät für eine neue Frage. Ich fand diese hier schon interessant.

Comment: Am einfachsten wäre es, »ich fangirle« durch »ich bin ein Fangirl« zu ersetzen. Das ist dann immer noch jugendsprachlich, aber weniger abgefahren.

Comment: @c.p. Eindeutschen kann ja grundsätzlich nur widerstandslos geschehen, und meistens ist es durch das Fehlen eines deutschen Begriffes, oder einer Abgrenzung der Bedeutung. Es ist z.B. ein Unterschied, ob die Frage über diesem Kommentar, oder super ist. Es ist, unabhängig davon, von großem Vorteil, neue Begriffe begrenzt auf eine Subkultur zu testen. Die Nützlichkeit drückt sich in dem grad der coolheit aus. Bzw. der Coolheit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ein "Fangirl" oder "Fanboy" meint einen unkritischen Fan von etwas oder jemandem (einem Künstler, einem Unternehmen etc.). Meist ist es abwertend gemeint, im Sinne von "War doch klar, dass die Fanboys sich diese Aktion auch noch schönreden" oder "wer XY jetzt noch verteidigt, ist doch nur ein blauäugiges Fangirlie". Ob "-girl" oder "-boy" richtet sich nach dem Geschlecht des Fans.

In diesem Fall wird "Fangirl" als Verb verwendet. "Sie fangirlt jemanden" heißt also etwa so viel wie "Sie ist ein Fangirl von jemandem". Außerdem ist der Begriff hier weniger abwertend, sondern eher selbstironisch gemeint. Da "fangirlen" und nicht "fanboyen" verwendet wird, ist der Fan vermutlich weiblich.